# trait with method returning copy of trait

Tags: scala

I want to create a method in a trait that returns a copy of the trait so something like this:

```
sealed trait thing {
  def attr1: String
  def attr2: String
  def paste(middle: String) : String = {
    return attr1 + middle + attr2;
  }
  //def new_thing(addOn: String) : thing = {
    // create new thing with addOn pasted to end of attr1 and attr2, but with other attributes preserved
 // }
}

case class objectA(
  attr1: String,
  attr2: String,
  attrA: String
) extends thing

case class objectB(
  attr1: String,
  attr2: String,
  attrB: String
) extends thing

object example {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val x = objectA("A", "B", "C")
    val y = x.new_thing("Z")
    // should return 'y: objectA = objectA(AZ, BZ, C)
  }
}
```

Creating a method in the case clase that does this is straight forward.

```
case clase objectA(
  attr1: String
  attr2: String
  attrA: String

) extends thing {
    def new_thing(addOn: String) : objectA = {
      return objectA(attr1 + addOn, attr2 + addOn, attrA)
    }
}
```

But since sealed traits have a copy method (edit no they don't) I feel like I shouldn't have to implement `new_thing` for each case class.

I am learning Scala so it is possible I am missing something obvious. Is this a case where I want to use F-bounded polymorphism? What is the most Scala way of dealing with this?

Comment: What makes you think that "sealed traits have a copy method"? They don't.

Comment: Me not reading this through https://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/copying-sealed-trait-instances-a-journey-through-generic-programming-and-shapeless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is to define the trait likewise (using `return` is discouraged):

```
sealed trait thing {
  def attr1: String
  def attr2: String
  def paste(middle: String): String = attr1 + middle + attr2
  def new_thing(addOn: String): thing
}
```

And then, for each case class I'll just override `new_thing` with the implementation I'm looking for:

```
case class objectA(attr1: String, attr2: String, attrA: String) extends thing {
  override def new_thing(addOn: String): objectA =
    objectA(attr1 + addOn, attr2 + addOn, attrA)
}
```

Therefore, you can proceed likewise:

```
scala> val a: objectA = objectA("a", "b", "c")
a: objectA = objectA(a,b,c)

scala> val b: objectA = a.new_thing(" plus a")
b: objectA = objectA(a plus a,b plus a,c)

scala> b
res0: objectA = objectA(a plus a,b plus a,c)
```